# full outer join by hand

Tags: sql, database, join

I am trying to understand full outer join by using these simple tables

```
t1
-----------
 a  | b
===========
 1  | 2
----------- 

t2
------------
  b  |  c
===========
  2  | 3
------------

t3
-------------
  a  |  c
=============
  4  |  5
-------------

To understand select * from t1 natural full outer join (t2 natural full outer join t3);
```

I tried first `select * from t2 natural full outer join t3`
Let me call this as `result`

```
-----------------
  a  |  b  |  c
=================
     | 2   | 3
----------------
  4  |     | 5
------------------
```

then I tried

select *  from t1 natural full outer join (result)

```
    t1             result
-----------      -----------------
 a  | b           a    |  b  | c
===========      =================
 1  | 2                | 2   | 3
-----------      ----------------
                    4  |     | 5
                 ------------------
```

Shouldn't this be

```
--------------------------
   a    |  b  |  c
===========================
   1    |  2  | 3
-------------------------
  4     |     | 5
```

I cannot quite understand how the sql query can give

```
 a | b | c 
---+---+---
 4 |   | 5
   | 2 | 3
 1 | 2 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `UNION ALL` (*ALL was specified to keep duplicates*).

```
SELECT  a, b, NULL as c FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT  NULL as a, b, c FROM t2
UNION ALL
SELECT  a, NULL as b, c FROM t3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/530dc/1)